# How do i make a number print on keypress on javascript

Tags: javascript

i built a website to generate random numbers, but how can i make it so if i press control it will show the number i want.

I have tried several methods but those didn't help me, i want it to print the number i want when control or enter is pressed.

It generates numbers between 1-100 randomly.

````
AOS.init();

// Selects elements in index.html
const display = document.querySelector('#display')
const generateButton = document.querySelector("#generate")
const minimumInput = document.querySelector('#minimum')
const maximumInput = document.querySelector('#maximum')

/**
 * Creates a random number in the given range
 * @param {*} range Difference between lowest and highest values
 */
function random(range) {

    // Returns random number
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range)
}

/**
 * Displays a random number of the given range
 */
function randomRange() {

    // Store value of minimumInput and maximumInput into variables and converts them into integer
    const minimumValue = parseInt(minimumInput.value)
    const maximumValue = parseInt(maximumInput.value)

    // Calculates and stores random number using random()
    let randomNumber = random(maximumValue - minimumValue) + minimumValue

    // Display randomNumber to user
    display.innerHTML = randomNumber
}

// Activates function once button is clicked
generateButton.addEventListener("click", randomRange)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add a `keydown` event for that

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {...})
```

Comment: my whole page disappeared when i added this code

Comment: it will run your code whenever you press a key .you can try it in  your console

Comment: but how do i make it to show up on my web page rather than on console? sorry im new to javascript

Comment: try setting the `innerText` instead of`innerHtml` to that random number

Comment: is there any other way to do it without touching this JS code? like put it on my index.html so when i press "C" on my keyboard on index.html , the number "5" appears on site?

Comment: as long as you are changing the `innerHTML` your page will disappear. you can write your logics  inside the script tag but that's not recommended

Comment: can we give it a try?

should i add 

```<script>document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {...}) </script>```

in index.html ?

Comment: yes ; include that script tag after the first script tag.
`<script defer>//your code</script>`

Comment: i added that line but now whenever i  press E nothing shows up on the website

Comment: here https://controlc.com/7d1a8d0e i want the number to appear between ```<header>
    <h2>Случайное число:</h2>
   
    </header>```

Comment: i see no script tag here

Comment: wait lemme redo it

Comment: there is only one script tag!. you should first reference the js file and right under that put your script tag

Comment: what is the name of your js file ? include that in your html code first then write your script
`<script src="yourFileName.js"></script>` and then open the scirpt tag

Comment: it's already there, here my full html code https://controlc.com/3cfa5955

Comment: try writing your script in `script tag` under this tag `<script src="./script.js"></script>`

Comment: tried it , nothing is showing up on my website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236060/discussion-between-nima-poshtiban-and-rock-life).